# Set attribute for object in for loop

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to set an attribute called "start" as either 1 or 2 depending on which line an object crosses first.

The error i get says "name 'start' is not defined"

I have tried to search all over the web but can't seem to find any similar problems.

The code is as follows:

I have tried to set it as start[i] = 1 and also start[arids[
                        currentcarsindex[i]]] = 1

```
for i in range(currentcars):  # loops through all current car ids on screen

            # grabs centroid of certain carid for current frame
            curcent = df.iloc[int(framenumber)][str(carids[currentcarsindex[i]])]

            # grabs centroid of certain carid for previous frame
            oldcent = df.iloc[int(framenumber - 1)][str(carids[currentcarsindex[i]])]

            if curcent:  # if there is a current centroid

                # On-screen text for current centroid

                cv2.drawMarker(image, (int(curcent[0]), int(curcent[1])), (0, 0, 255), cv2.MARKER_STAR, markerSize=5,
                               thickness=1, line_type=cv2.LINE_AA)

                if oldcent:  # checks if old centroid exists
                    # adds radius box from previous centroid to current centroid for visualization
                    xstart = oldcent[0] - maxrad
                    ystart = oldcent[1] - maxrad
                    xwidth = oldcent[0] + maxrad
                    yheight = oldcent[1] + maxrad
                    cv2.rectangle(image, (int(xstart), int(ystart)), (int(xwidth), int(yheight)), (0, 125, 0), 1)

                    # checks if old centroid is on or below line and curcent is on or above line
                    # to count cars and that car hasn't been counted yet
                    if oldcent[1] >= lineypos2 and curcent[1] <= lineypos2 and carids[
                        currentcarsindex[i]] not in caridscrossed:

                        cv2.line(image, (0, lineypos2), (width, lineypos2), (0, 0, 255), 5)
                        start = 1


                    # checks if old centroid is on or above line and curcent is on or below line
                    # to count cars and that car hasn't been counted yet
                    elif oldcent[1] <= lineypos3 and curcent[1] >= lineypos3 and carids[
                        currentcarsindex[i]] not in caridscrossed:

                        cv2.line(image, (0, lineypos2), (width, lineypos2), (0, 0, 125), 5)
                        start = 2


                    if oldcent[1] >= lineypos3 and curcent[1] <= lineypos3 and start == 1 and carids[
                        currentcarsindex[i]] not in caridscrossed:
                        carscrossedup = carscrossedup + 1
                        caridscrossed.append(
                            currentcarsindex[i])  # adds car id to list of count cars to prevent double counting


                    # checks if old centroid is on or above line and curcent is on or below line
                    # to count cars and that car hasn't been counted yet
                    elif oldcent[1] <= lineypos2 and curcent[1] >= lineypos2 and start == 2 and carids[
                        currentcarsindex[i]] not in caridscrossed:
                        carscrosseddown = carscrosseddown + 1
                        caridscrossed.append(
                            currentcarsindex[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare variables at the level of scope they will be used.

```py
if oldcent:  # checks if old centroid exists
                    # adds radius box from previous centroid to current centroid for visualization
    xstart = oldcent[0] - maxrad
    ystart = oldcent[1] - maxrad
    xwidth = oldcent[0] + maxrad
    yheight = oldcent[1] + maxrad
    cv2.rectangle(image, (int(xstart), int(ystart)), (int(xwidth), int(yheight)), (0, 125, 0), 1)
    start = None

    if oldcent[1] >= lineypos2 and curcent[1] <= lineypos2 and carids[
            currentcarsindex[i]] not in caridscrossed:
        ...
```

Now, `start` should be available to you.

Comment: I had that in mind, however since this is in a for loop for each frame, I want to keep the start value for next frame as well and not reset it to 'none'

Comment: In that case, move your start variable to before the for loop.

Comment: Hmm.. for each carID in carids[currentcarsindex[i]] i want to assign them a Start value like start[i] or carids[currentcarsindex[i]].start, that can be checked. Therefore I kind of want to create the attribute in the foor loop

Answer (score 0):

You have the following flow in your code

```
if (condition_1):
    start = 1
elif (condition_2):
    start = 2
# There is no else clause. If neither condition evaluates as True then "start"
# will not have been defined

if (condition_that_uses_start):
    # Because start is not defined this will cause your error
    pass
```